# Build multiple github pull requests at same time but merge every PR on latest branch

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, teamcity

Lets assume we are building (CI) every pull request in github using Jenkins, Teamcity or whatever and merge PR when build is successful. Every PR must be built on latest branch. Want to know how people are able to achieve this?

> ```
> PRs    Start Time   Jenkins Build      Build Finished
>
> PR1   (10:00) ---> Building(30 mins) -->10:30  ---->  Merged in Develop
> PR2   (10:05) ---> Building(30 mins) -->10:35  ---->  Merged in Develop
> PR3   (10:10) ---> Building(30 mins) -->10:40  ---->  Merged in Develop
> ```

I have a problem with this approach. After PR1 is merged in develop branch(at 10:30), PR2 and PR3 were not building on latest branch anymore, they are on old state of develop branch (before PR1 is merged).

In Github there is an option to make sure protected branches are up-to-date before merging. "Require branches to be up to date before merging". If we choose this option, PR2 and PR3 cannot be merged in develop and we get "update branch" button enabled for PR which will make sure PR is rebased from develop branch.

Now PR2 and P3 are rebased on develop branch but not verified on latest code so, we build them again. Which is taking more time to build every PR. Its like 2 to 3 times of build.

How do you guys achieve this in your organizations?

Answer (score 0):

*Fact :*

- if your validation process takes 30 mins,
- if you need to validate :

  1. `PR1` alone
  2. `PR2` on top of validated `PR1`
  3. `PR3` on top of validated `PR1 + PR2`

then :

- you are looking at a minimum of 1h30 to integrate 3 PRs

*How to change this :*

- optimize your build job
- if you can validate a PR by running only a subset of tasks (e.g : run unit tests, but no need to build static assets ...), split your CI jobs into two jobs : one "validation" job and one "build" job
- change your pipeline : for example, you can have your CI automatically validate new PRs, but require some manual step to merge the PRs into master and manually trigger the build job on the result

Comment: Thanks @LeGEC.  We are trying to avoid any manual step in this process to improve the productivity of Developers.  Currently, our developers submit PR and assumes they are done with their job. Our automation does all build/validations etc and merges it in master. If automation fails in any case, it should send feedback to Dev to take a look.